# Android countdownTimer error on button click

Tags: java, android

I want that user will input minutes in the edit text box and after that when  the submit button is clicked the counter will start . but what is the error here? it shows that unfortunately the app has stopped.  Please help.

```
      package com.example.asifsabir.counterapps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv1;
    EditText et1;
    Button bt1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        bt1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);



        bt1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int min =Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                        if (!et1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                            final int sec = min*60;

                            new CountDownTimer(sec, 1000) {

                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    tv1.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%02d",
                                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    tv1.setText("done!");
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );


    }

}
```

and the xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="enter sec"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="submit"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="count"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#3559da"
        android:textSize="80sp" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

error logs:

```
339-25339/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-24 05:25:44.927 25339-25339/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:25339
03-24 05:25:44.957 25339-25353/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-24 05:25:45.127 25339-25339/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.asifsabir.counterapps, PID: 25339
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asifsabir.counterapps/com.example.asifsabir.counterapps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5702)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                       at com.example.asifsabir.counterapps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5702) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
03-24 05:28:37.087 25339-25339/com.example.asifsabir.counterapps D/Process: killProcess, pid=25339
03-24 05:28:37.087 25339-25339/com.example.asifsabir.counterapps D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:138 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert the `EditText` value into integer in `onCreate()` -

```
int min =Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
```

Now in `onCreate()` , at that time your 
`EditText` will be empty and 
`et1.getText().toString()` will be `""`
and hence 
`Integer.parseInt("")` will apparently throw `NumberFormatException`

To avoid this you need to do 2 most important things -

1. First check for empty string

   ```
   if (!et1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
      //convert here
   }
   ```
2. Also make your `EditText` in your xml to accept only numbers so that it doesn't throws `NumberFormatException` again in future.

Comment: Add this -    android:inputType="number"

Comment: Thanks! 
 
great ! it is now working! but another thing: if I input another number when a coutdown is running. both countdowns are being overlapped. how can I stop this problem so that the previous one is erased and the last one starts?

Comment: Do a .cancel() on the original CountdownTimer before starting the new one.

Comment: where should I use this cancel method?

Comment: Don't create anonymous CountDownTimer instance. Create  like CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(.....). And when you want to start another CountDownTimer after cancelling the previous one then use timer.cancel() and create a new one .

Answer (score 0):

you should get Integer.parseInt when click event happens, and your input must be in millis:

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int min = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                    int sec = min*60;
                    int millis = sec*1000;
                    new CountDownTimer(millis, 1000) {
                    //(...)
```

And you should also validate before if EditText is not empty, to avoid NumberFormat exceptions like you get.

```
if (et1.getText().toString().isEmpty())
   //notice user to input some number
   return;
```

Comment: I have written the code as you have said but after clicking submit it shows "done".  No count down is starting

Comment: remember your countDownTimer must be in millis, not seconds. (just edited my code)

Comment: great ! it is now working! but another thing: if I input another number when a coutdown is running. both countdowns are being overlapping. how can I stop this problem so that the previous one is erased and the last one starts?

Comment: you are allways creating new counter. First create a CountDownTimer as global var (CountDownTimer counter). any time you start new timer use that instance. and cancel() it before start new counting.

Comment: If any answer given helps you're question, upvote and accept that answer to close this question. thank you